# Most Effecient Railgun Design

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-circuits, material-science, electrical-engineering

This is my first post on this forum. My name is Kavika and I am a high school freshman.

For a school project, I am designing and engineering a functional rail gun. I am on a budget and am wondering what the best materials would be to use while keeping the cost low. My original design was several capacitors (5100 uf, 400V) wired to two, 3 foot metal rails. These rails would be stabilized by acrylic which I would layer to make the barrels. The first layer would serve as the base of the barrel, the middle layer the walls, and the final layer the top of the barrel.

I am in the process of making a materials list and the biggest cost are the capacitors. They are about 45 dollars each and I was hoping to buy 8 of them, coming to a grand total of about $360. Unfortunately, this goes over the budget my school has allotted me. How many of these components and of what power would I need to see visible results in my projectile velocity while keeping the cost to a minimum?

Are there any alternative cheaper materials to acrylic that would be both non-conductive and rigid strength? The current cost for this material is about $60.

I was originally going to have my rails copper which would have been about $30, but I am considering using aluminum because of its low cost and lower, but still good, conductivity.

I will be experimenting launching a projectile made of compressed aluminum foil because of its availability. I have heard reports of this material vaporizing when run through a rail gun. Should I be concerned about the rails if I decide to make them out of aluminum, that they would break down more rapidly than they would otherwise?

I would welcome any other recommendations from you if you have them. I am aware of the danger involved in this project and have had experience with electronics and will be working under adult supervision. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your ambition is admirable! That said, both the cost and the safety factor would probably be much more manageable if you scaled this project down, especially when it comes to those capacitors. I understand the desire to build something huge and awesome, but believe me when I say that even a smaller railgun will not fail to impress.

Answer (score 2):

Good Evening,

First of all - COOL!
Second - what you are wanting to build can be very dangerous.  When working with high voltage electricity, extreme caution must be taken.

Ebay would be your best bet or a website dedicated to selling scrap electrical components.  But you are correct, new 5100 uF, 400 V caps will set you back 45 a piece new.

While there are no propellants inside the gauss gun, there is a lot of pressure generated from the firing of a gauss gun.  The opposing magnetic field generated by the current can blow apart weak copper rails. (Lorentz Law is a mutha) At higher amperage, the rails themselves will create their own magnetic fields that will oppose the rails opposite of themselves.

If you are set on building one... try somthing like this:  http://www.doityourselfgadgets.com/2013/10/homemade-railgun.html

Comment: Do you have any idea of the velocity that would be imparted onto a projectile with the amount of current and voltage in the capacitors?

Answer (score 1):

As it so happens, I am also in high school and I did a similar project for science fair a few years back!

I was also recommend a scaled down version, it is actually attainable with much less dangerous materials.

I used a V made from two wood planks, a series of Samarium-Cobalt magnets and chrome-steel ball bearings, and a secured large foam target to conduct my experiment. I purchased the square magnets and all bearings online for a relatively cheap amount.

This form of a railgun is known as a magnetic linear accelerator, or a Gauss rifle.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bZDxGPZTBMg

This link demonstrates the concept I'm speaking of, I would link my project but I can't find it.

Best of luck with your project and the rest of school year!